# Saving all nodes from a big XML to SQL Database table in XMLType column using SSIS efficiently

Tags: sql, xml, ssis, xml-parsing, xmlnodelist

I have a XML with many records as nodes in it. I need to save each record in xml format a SQL server table in column of XML datatype .

I can perform this task in SSIS using "XML Task Editor" to count all the nodes and using "For Loop Container" and read Node value using "XML Task Editor" and save it database.

Another option is using Script task, reading the XML file and save each node in a loop.

Please suggest a better approach which is efficient with big files.

Below is sample of Input XML File. I need to save each (3 records in below example) "RECORD" full node in XML form in SQL Server database table which has a column with xml datatype.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have modified the content, hope its clear now.

Comment: What does "big" mean? 1Mb or 1Tb?

Comment: @MichaelKay Each file(xml) is approx. 1-2MB with 500+ nodes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest 2 step approach.

1. Use SSIS **Import Column** Transformation in a Data Flow Task to load entire XML file into a staging table single row column.
2. Use stored procedure to produce individual RECORD XML fragments as separate rows and INSERT them into a final destination table.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @staging_tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @staging_tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<root>
    <RECORD UI="F298AF1F"></RECORD>
    <RECORD UI="4C6AAA65"></RECORD>
</root>');

-- INSERT INTO destination_table (ID, xml_record)
SELECT id   
    , c.query('.') AS xml_record
FROM @staging_tbl
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root/RECORD') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| id | xml_record |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `<RECORD UI="F298AF1F" />` |
| 1 | `<RECORD UI="4C6AAA65" />` |

Comment: Thanks @YitzhakKhabinsky but step 1 is not working, as its not able to load full file in database table, file text is truncated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I85CaBKcXs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U00ld7jEK8Q
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNsm0Qv3TFU

Comment: What column data type you are using in the staging table?

Comment: In SSIS for the  Import Column Transformation you need to use DT_NTEXT data type in the Import Column Output.

Comment: In Import Column Transformation - it is DT_NTEXT, and in database staging I tried with varbinary(max) and varchar(max)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/867243/loading-xml-file-into-xml-column-using-ssis.html

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but with DT_NTEXT to XML mapping - I am getting the data like 爼潯㹴਍†䐼⁓䥕∽㉆㠹䙁䘱㐭䑆ⵃ䘴䕅㠭䈸ⵂ㙄ぁ㤲㡅

Comment: its the same behavior with XML datatype and nvarchar(max).  works fine with DT_NTEXT >> varbinary(max) and varchar(max) but its truncated

Comment: loading it from DT_NTEXT to varbinary(max) and cast(XmlFileData as xml) returns full content in XML.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you.

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak Khabinsky for your help. Not sure why DT_NTEXT to XML or nvarchar(max) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nodes() method to return a rowset of nodes in the xml document. This is the simplest example:

```
select node_table.xml_node_column.query('.') node 
from xmldocument
cross apply xmldocument.nodes('/root/RECORD') node_table(xml_node_column)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: thank you @Gerballi but I need to have xmldocument in above query in database first, thats the first step.

Comment: I never use SSIS. I'd use openrowset to read the file from disk on the server I think: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1643/using-openrowset-to-read-large-files-into-sql-server/